# mongodb update push sub-subdocument

Tags: mongodb

The question is quite easy. I have the following document in mongoDb:

```
_id : ObjectId("519e3c14ade67153e9a003a0")
status:1, 
name:"name",
details:
{ 
  crm:115, 
  webs: 
  [
    { tag:"blog" , url:"http://..."} 
  ], 
  contacts:
  [
    {
      _id:ObjectId("009e37e1ade67153e9a0039e"),
      name:"me", 
      phones:
      [
        { tag:"home", number:"123..." },
        {tag:"mobile", number:"123456789"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to update one fo the phones in the subdocument details.contacts doing this:

```
db.new.update(
{
  _id : ObjectId("519e3c14ade67153e9a003a0"), 
  "details.contacts._id": ObjectId("009e37e1ade67153e9a0039e"),
  "details.contacts.phones.tag":"home"
},
{
  $set: 
  {
    "details.contacts.$.phones.$": 
    {
      tag:"home", 
      number:"965923777"
    }
  }
})
```

and finally I get the following error: Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.

There is anyway to update the document in this way or i should send all the phones to update this field?

Comment: This is weird, it is not taking the value of $ ( the 2nd one ). If you replace the 2nd $ with 0 or 1, this works ( i.e. we are explicitly telling that we want to update 0th or 1st entry inside 'phone' )

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651500/mongodb-operator multiple `$` operators are not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I couldn't find this answer even if I supposed that was the problem :)